# gitosis-init for 2nd user? (need to make a new owner for gitosis-admin)

Tags: git, gitosis

Here's the situation:

We have a git repository, managed by gitosis. One user user managed the gitosis-admin repository (via git-init).

Now we need to add other users to access gitosis-admin, however the initial user's laptop died, so they do not have access to the gitosis-admin repository (normally you would just commit a change to that repository to add users).

So...how do I add new users to the git projects that gitosis managed, when I don't have access to gitosis-admin? All I have access to is the server where git and gitosis are installed.

I tried running 'sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/key.pub' for the 2nd user, but that did not work. gitosis keeps asking for the 'git' ssh password when trying to clone the gitosis-admin repository. And without cloning the gitosis-admin repo it doesn't seem like I can add any users as authorized user to make changes to that or other repos...

Any wizards know how to handle this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this tutorial solved it: http://jeetworks.org/node/18

Had to checkout gitosis-admin locally on the server and make the changes.

Phew!

Comment: Yep. That's how you admin the rights on gitosis-managed repos. Incidentally (and I'm sorry if this is super bad news at this point), but gitosis is abandoned and deprecated. You should be using gitolite instead.

Comment: Please consider using gitolite instead. Gitosis is no longer actively developed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. When did gitosis get deprecated?